# If $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\ n^3 a_n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n$ converges conditionally. Prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\ n^3 a_n$ diverges.

Comment: The logic in the OP is flawed since it is possible that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^3a_{n+1}}{n^3a_n}\right|=1$.

Comment: Nope. The first step is wrong - that limit might not exist, and if it did exist it could equal $1$. **Hint:** The terms of a convergent series tend to $0$, hence are bounded in absolute value.

Comment: is the entire solution wrong?

Comment: In future show any attempts  you have made or you may get negative responses, and the moderators (not me) might close your Q.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum n^3a_n$ converged, then the sequence $(n^3a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would converge to $0$ and in particular would be bounded.
We'd have $|n^3a_n|\leqslant C$ for some $C>0$ and all $n$, so that $|a_n|\leqslant C/n^3$.
But then $\sum a_n$ would be absolutely convergent, which contradicts the hypothesis that it converges conditionally.

---

The same argument shows that if $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is positive and $\sum 1/b_n$ converges, then $\sum b_na_n$ cannot converge.

Answer (score 0):

**Abridged solution.** If the series $(n^3a_n)$ converged, then we would have $|a_n| \leq |c_n|/n^3$ with $|c_n| \to 0,$ a contradiction to the hypothesis of conditional convergence of the series $(a_n).$